# How to 'unrender' MathJax equations?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

We all know that MathJax renders elements on window onload by default (and can be refreshed using `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200545/mathjax-js-how-to-recall-restart-it)), but is there a way to 'unrender' the elements? So for example, after the page just loaded, I can click a button, and all the elements will turn back into their TeX code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MathJax hides the original LaTeX code in an element called `MathJax-Element-x`, which contains the original code. So what I did was simply hide all elements with the class `MathJax_Display`, in which the formatted version appeared, and showed all elements starting with `MathJax-Element-`. Seemed to work fine.

**EDIT**: Instead of selecting `MathJax_Display` elements, I had to select all the elements inside `MathJax_Display`, like `MathJax_Display *`. I also had to change the type of element the LaTeX code was put in, as it was in a script.

Comment: If you managed to unrender MathJax on a page, could you share the script/button that does it?

Comment: @user612313 I'm sorry - this was from so long ago I'm pretty sure I lost the script itself :D

Comment: @user612313 I think though, all you need to do is grab the original LaTeX code, put it in another element, and then just render the LaTeX using `MathJax.Render` or something - gah, I can't remember anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the original TeX code is stored by MathJax, so you can use some javascript to put it back.  There is an example of how to do this on the [MathJax users forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/IwXGeBqwN1s/Q3DaXsAHpxUJ) that I think may be what you are looking for.