# Reload Mathjax = forcing typesetting once again

Tags: javascript, mathjax

i wanted to reload Mathjax, i.e. force typesetting once again when clicking on a button.

Therefore i wrote the following code:

```
<button onClick="newTask()"></button>
```

The reload function contains:

```
function newTask(){

  // This is a function creating a new task, i.e. replacing HTML between some tags

  newCode();



 // Now i want to renew typesetting by calling Mathjax

  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
}
```

My script did not work. Where do I have to put the line "MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);" ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Any errors in the console? Does `newCode()` work as intended?

Comment: newCode() works perfectly fine, it renders mathjax code like $$ my equation $$.

Comment: I only ask because the MathJax call seems ok. Have you verified `newCode()` by not calling MathJax at all?

Comment: Is newCode asynchronous by any chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recall or restart MathJax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200545/how-to-recall-or-restart-mathjax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why it works now or did not before, but i changed the setup to the following:

inside the html file:

```
<button onClick="createBasicTask()">
```

where createBasicTask() is a new version of newTask()

and in the js file:

```
function createBasicTask(){
...
newTypeset();
}
```

with newTypeset being

```
function newTypeset(){
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
}
```

if you are interested, the whole script will be a task generator, the full source can be viewed here:
[Source](http://alexander-pastor.de/files/latest/study/maths/complex/complex.js)

Live Demo (first task):
[Demo](http://alexander-pastor.de/aufgabengenerator.html)

Comment: Other methods to try: `Rerender`, `Reprocess`

Answer (score 4):

For me using MathJax 3, I had to replace `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` with `MathJax.typeset();` in Alex's solution.