# Rendering Mathjax in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, mathjax

I'm trying a number of different ways to render mathjax in highcharts but nothing is working! Please let me know if this is possible. You can see in the fiddle that Mathjax is being rendered, just not in the chart:

```
categories: [
        '\(+x \)',
        '\\(+x \\)',
        '/\(+x /\)',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nscozzaro/nr986r0x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format `'\\(+x \\)'` is already being replaced in Highcharts, however, you have not enabled HTML for the labels. Simply add this code:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        useHTML: true
    }
    categories: [
        '\\(+x \\)',
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Or see [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr986r0x/4/) example.

The same `useHTML` feature exists for `legend`, `series.dataLabels`, `title`, `subtitle`, `tooltip` and a few other places where you can use text. If in doubt, search the API.

Comment: A follow-up question, regarding the tooltip: currently "useHTML: true" is set inside the tooltip, but the mathjax isn't being rendered in the tooltip. What's the reason for this and how can I make it render in the tooltip?

Comment: And a last question is why is double slashing necessary:   \\( \\) as opposed to just the regular \( \)?

Comment: First question is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5200579/2732991). MathJax is just run initially. You need to call some additional code to run it at the times when new math might appear for it to re-scan. Double slash is because backslash is an escape character in JS, so you need to escape the escape character for it to show up.