# Mathjax render only on first page of the data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, latex, mathjax

I am using a datatable to show maths questions. The max Equations are added as latex Method. I use the below Js script to render Mathjax equations,

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}

  });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
```

but in the datatable the first pagination only shows the correct rendered equations,next all pages are showing the latex.

Comment: it is about rerender about mathjax, maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200545/how-to-recall-or-restart-mathjax) will help you

Comment: i solved by putting  in datatable `$('#example').DataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
    }
} );`

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery DataTables only first page exist in DOM, that's why pages other than first remain "as is".

You need to use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to handle table redraw event and re-initialize all custom controls there. For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        // MathJax.Hub.Config({
        //    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
        // });

        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]); 
    }
} );
```

I'm not confident that `MathJax.Hub.Config()` could be run multiple times but that should give you a start.

See [MathJax - Configuration](http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) for more details on how MathJax could be configured.

**UPDATE**

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864810/mathjax-render-only-on-first-page-of-the-data-table/35874863#comment59445101_35874863), calling `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` inside `drawCallback` solved the problem.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.

Comment: i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined`

Comment: i solved by putting in datatable `$('#example').DataTable( { "drawCallback": function( settings ) { MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]); } } );`