# Dynamic MathJax Examples

Tags: mathjax

My question to understand better Dynamic MathJax Examples is very simple:

In this page about  [DOM manipulation with mathjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511332/dom-manipulation-with-mathjax) I have posted the following comment:

> This last snippet works, but I would be happy to understand it better in using it my local server. Unfortunately, pasting this code is not enough and the script does not work in my apache2 local server. I need help.

A simple index.php working with Dynamic MathJax would be helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is this link useful : https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html ? If not, can you publish your own code? Does your apache2 server have Internet access?

Comment: Hi, this link was helpful: https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/ thanks for your help !